# how to add multiple labels in doughnut chart in ChartJS library?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am working on react(chart.js) and i need multiple label on my chart,one inside and other for outside the doughnut chart. Anyone know how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

use plugin-labels for chart-js, it support multiple labels also.
[plugin labels](https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels)